# PHP getting key from array using echo (undefined index)

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get current key from this array using echo:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [author] => Porsche God
            [url] => https://youtu.be/Rpn_qOQaa3o
        )
    )
)
```

I have tried this things: `echo $video[0]['author];`, `echo $video['author];`, only thing which works is `echo '<pre>'; print_r($video); echo '</pre>';`, also tried to read some similar problems but they didn't help either.

```
$youtubers_id = array();

$youtubers_id[] = 'UCH7Hj6l_xDmbyvjQOA5Du0g';
$youtubers_id[] = 'UC08WkcNFYsUpxbolNUZvUmw';

$array_len = count($youtubers_id) - 1;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $array_len; $i++) {
    $video[] = get_user_videos($youtubers_id[$i]);
}

function get_user_videos($user_id) {
    $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id='. $user_id;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
        $author = (string)$xml->entry[$i]->author[0]->name[0];

        $url = $xml->entry[$i]->children('yt', true)->videoId[0];
        $url = "https://youtu.be/" . $url;
    
        $video[] = array('author'=>$author, 'url'=>$url);
    }
    
    return $video;
}

echo $video['author'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: solved

```
$video[] = array('author'=>$author, 'url'=>$url);
```

replaced with:

```
$video = array('author'=>$author, 'url'=>$url);
```

it wasn't working because I had there 1 more array inside